# can't use igniterealtime smack on android Could not resolve xpp3:xpp3:1.1.4c

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, smack, asmack

I have failed to use [smack jabber](https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/wiki/Smack-4.3-Readme-and-Upgrade-Guide) on android.
app.gradle

implementation "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.3.1"
implementation "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.3.1"

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve org.minidns:minidns-client:0.3.3.

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve xpp3:xpp3:1.1.4c.

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve org.jxmpp:jxmpp-core:0.6.3.

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve org.jxmpp:jxmpp-jid:0.6.3.

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve org.minidns:minidns-core:0.3.3.

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve org.minidns:minidns-hla:0.3.3.
```

Gradle build failed.

These are my gradle files

app.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "ug.situla.passengermvp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.1.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:16.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.maps.android:android-maps-utils:0.5'
    implementation "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-java7:4.3.1"
    implementation "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.3.1"
    implementation "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.3.1"
    //implementation "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.2.0"
    //implementation "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.2.0"
    //implementation "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-im:4.2.0"
    //implementation "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-extensions:4.2.0"
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
}
```

build.gradle

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        //maven {url 'http://localhost:8081/repository/google/'}
        //maven {url 'http://localhost:8081/repository/jcenter/'}
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'
        }
        mavenCentral()
        //google()
        //jcenter()
     }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Comment: You are missing `implementation "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-java7:4.3.1"` dependency

Comment: adding it has no effect . Error is still there

Comment: Check my answer below

Comment: Thanks, I have posted my full gradle files for full context. Still showing the error

Comment: 1) You dont have set the repositories correctly in the buildscript block of the project build.gradle
2) Why are you removing xpp3?

Comment: I have added the repositories you posted to the buildscript block-> error still showing. (2)igniterealtime suggest we do that for a minimal smack configuration, here https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/wiki/Smack-4.3-Readme-and-Upgrade-Guide

Comment: Have you tried to close and reopen android studio? The classpath should not be a problem here... If you comment the 3 lines of smack implementations everything works fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Be sure that in your project `build.gradle` you have:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots'
        }
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

And in you app `build.gradle` in the dependencies block:

```
dependencies {
   implementation "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-java7:4.3.0"
   implementation "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-android:4.3.0"
   implementation "org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-tcp:4.3.0"
}
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
}
```

Documentation reference: https://github.com/igniterealtime/Smack/wiki/Smack-4.3-Readme-and-Upgrade-Guide

Comment: Thanks, I have no idea why but its now compiling .  Weird

Comment: Sometimes Android Studio remains stucked and has weird behaviours, when this happens the first thing to do is restart it and see if that solves the problem :)

Comment: Also this line seems required. I had left it out `configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'xpp3', module: 'xpp3'
}`

Comment: Yeah that line is probably required as the documentation says, I've updated my answer for completeness

Comment: The smack version 4.3.1 also triggers the error. Other versions dont have issues

Comment: That's really strange, so with version 4.3.1 is not building? Maybe you can file an issue here: https://issues.igniterealtime.org/projects/SMACK/issues/SMACK-636?filter=allopenissues